# JavaScript validation of html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I have a PHP file containing a HTML registration form. The form consists of a few fields including a phone number, password and repeat password field.

I would like these fields to be validated and require some guidance on how to validate the users input. These fields should be required and the two password fields should match.

If it fails validation I would like the user to have feedback and the form to be prevented from being submitted.

If it passes then the form should be submitted.

```
<div id="id02" class="modal">
<form class="modal-content animate" action="register.php" method="post">    
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <label><b>Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>     
        <label><b>Phone No.:</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone number" name="phone" required>  
        <label><b>Date of Birth:</b></label>
        <input type="date" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" name="dob" required>
        <label><b>E-mail:</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        <label><b>Password:</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <label><b>Repeat Password:</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>     
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
        <div class="clearfix">      
            <button type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>     
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) 
{
    if (event.target == modal) 
    {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: No one is going to do your homework for you: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: a quick search would give you plenty of out-of-the-box solutions ie: [jQuery Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp (one of the first google results when googling for your question. You might want to do so yourself the next time).

You might want to adapt your code like this:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="register.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="formToValidate" method="post">
```

[...] your other code [...]

```
function validateForm() {

    // get value of phone number field
    var x = document.forms["formToValidate"]["phone"].value;

    // check phone number for being empty
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Phone number must be filled in");
        // return false to interupt the POST request.
        return false;
    }

    // copy, paste and adapt for the other form elements

}
```